# Output text size in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get only first (say) 200 characters from my object Article (which is in a table `articles` with aattributes `content` and `title`)?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rails' [TextHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001743) has a `truncate`  method.

So, in your views, you just have to do :

```
<%= truncate @article.content, :length => 50 %>
```

Where 50 is the number of characters you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):004:0> '0123456789'[3,7]
=> "3456789"
irb(main):005:0> '0123456789'[3..7]
=> "34567"
irb(main):006:0> '0123456789'[3...7]
=> "3456"
```

Above code and outputs are self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

now there is a gem; Auto_excerpt, at github.
https://github.com/RipTheJacker/auto_excerpt.